# how to determine what type of the union is used when output?

Tags: c, struct, unions

I used a union type in the struct to define whether this person is a student or a staff. When i tried to output the information in the struct array, i found it was hard for me to figure out what kind of this person was ,not to say output the further information. Do not tell me stop using union, sorry, i was asked to do so.
Hers's my simplified data structure:

```
typedef union student_or_staff{
    char *program_name;
    char *room_num;
}student_or_staff;

typedef struct people{
    char *names;
    int age;
    student_or_staff s_or_s;
}people[7];
```

Comment: It's not 'hard', it's impossible. Add a flag to `student_or_staff` to indicate what is what.

Comment: you cannot do this kind of thing out of the box.

Comment: If you were told to do so and that this is an exercise, I'd be curious to see what are the precise instructions

Comment: How can *you* tell what it was? I don't see any distinction.

Comment: thanks! i will add another parameter in the struct to flag what kind of union it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in C but as a workaround you can add a type along your union like this

```
enum { student_type, staff_type } PEOPLE_TYPE;
typedef union student_or_staff{
char *program_name;
char *room_num;
}student_or_staff;

typedef struct people{
char *names;
int age;
student_or_staff s_or_s;
PEOPLE_TYPE people_type;
}people[7];
```

Then you just set that along with your union when you assign your struct.

Comment: ----------------------------thanks---------------------------------

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know what is stored in a `union` is to include this information in some other place.

There are two common situations that happen when you deal with an array of `union`s (or `struct`s that hold a `union`):

- All `union`s in an array hold the same type, or
- Each `union` may hold its own type.

When all `union`s in an array hold the same type, a single variable that indicates the type the `union`s hold is sufficient.

When each `union` could hold a different type, a common approach is to wrap it in a `struct`, and add a flag indicating which way the `union` is set. Using your example, the flag should be added to `struct people`, like this:

```
enum student_staff_flag {
    student_flag
,   staff_flag
};
typedef struct people{
    char *names;
    int age;
    enum student_staff_flag s_or_s_flag;
    student_or_staff s_or_s;
}people[7];
```

Comment: ----------------------------thanks---------------------------------